# How to create scatterplot over time in R with this dataset

Tags: r, scatter-plot

When I try to create a scatter plot this way it comes out as a flat line. Here is the header of my data:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqYwX.png)

```
> head(seattle_thefts)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  report_date_time    offense            
  <dttm>              <chr>              
1 2020-02-04 13:54:37 Motor Vehicle Theft
2 2020-02-04 13:11:35 Motor Vehicle Theft
3 2020-02-04 09:46:13 Motor Vehicle Theft
4 2020-02-03 16:02:33 Motor Vehicle Theft
5 2020-02-03 15:49:24 Motor Vehicle Theft
6 2020-02-03 13:16:00 Motor Vehicle Theft
```

How do I create a plot over time of each occurrence by month or year? For example, a scatter plot where it shows how many occurrences there were in January 2020, then February 2020, etc.

This just creates a flat line:

```
ggplot(seattle_thefts, aes(x = report_date_time, y = offense)) +
  geom_point()
```

I tried to change it to a numeric value:

```
seattle_thefts$offense <- mutate(seattle_thefts, offense = 1)

seattle_thefts %>% 
  group_by(month = floor_date(report_date_time, 'month')) %>% 
  summarize(sum_of_thefts = sum(offense))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you assigned the change of `offense` from `mutate` looks weird since it would return a `tibble` or a `data.frame` depending on the data type of `seattle_thefts`. Try to look at `seattle_thefts` after you did the "change".

I just modified how you did your `mutate()` in the common usage syntax for `mutate()`

```
seattle_thefts <- seattle_thefts %>% mutate( offense = 1)

seattle_thefts %>% 
  group_by(month = floor_date(report_date_time, 'month')) %>% 
  summarize(sum_of_thefts = sum(offense)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month,sum_of_thefts ))+
  geom_point()
```

here is a shorter alternative where you wont need to change to numeric which just uses `n()` to count the number of rows per the grouped `month`

```
seattle_thefts %>% 
  group_by(month = floor_date(report_date_time, 'month')) %>% 
  summarize(sum_of_thefts =n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month,sum_of_thefts ))+
  geom_point()
```

Comment: `count(month = floor_date(report_date_time, "month"), name = "num_of_thefts") %>%` can replace the group_by + summarize, if you like.